# Error creating Observable from Event

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to create an Observable sequence from an event. The event has the following signature:

```
event SensorValueChangedEventHandler SensorValueChanged;
```

I am trying to create the Observable in the following way:

```
var eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEvent(
                                (EventHandler<SensorValueChangedEventArgs> ev) => new SensorValueChangedEventHandler(ev), 
                                ev => CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged += ev,
                                ev => CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged -= ev);
```

However, the compiler is failing with the following error:

```
Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Action' to `DeviceMotion.Plugin.Abstractions.SensorValueChangedEventHandler'
```

I am wondering if someone can comment on how to correctly create an observable from this event.

Comment: What is the definition of your SensorValueChangedEventHandler?

Comment: @Evk ```public delegate void SensorValueChangedEventHandler (object sender, SensorValueChangedEventArgs e);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need to do it like this:

```
var eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEvent<SensorValueChangedEventHandler, SensorValueChangedEventArgs>(
    handler => (sender, args) => handler(args),
    ev => CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged += ev,
    ev => CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged -= ev);
```

In the first argument you tell how to map between `Action<SensorValueChangedEventArgs>` (basically `OnNext`) and your delegate. In second and third arguments you pass subscribe and unsubscribe functions.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: @Enigmativity I've compiled and ran that before posting, using latest Rx from nuget package.

Comment: Maybe you mean I use variable "p" instead of OP's CrossDeviceMotion.Current, but that does not matter.

Comment: Can I suggest that you use `handler => (sender, args) => handler(args)` as the first parameter? It's a lot less messy than declaring a handler and returning it.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using an obsolete method for observing standard .NET events - it's no longer `FromEvent` - you should be using `FromEventPattern`.

The code should look like this:

```
var eventAsObservable =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<SensorValueChangedEventHandler, SensorValueChangedEventArgs>(
                ev => CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged += ev,
                ev => CrossDeviceMotion.Current.SensorValueChanged -= ev);
```

The `.FromEvent` method is used for handling non-standard (doesn't comply with `(object sender, XxxEventArgs e)` signature) type events.

Comment: This is not true that FromEvent is "obsolete". It is used when event does not conform to the standard .NET event pattern (sender + event args). While in this case you indeed can use FromEventPattern (or FromEvent) - there are cases where you cannot use FromEventPattern.

Comment: @Evk - Sorry, that's what I meant when I said it was obsolete for "observing events". I meant the standard .NET event pattern.

Comment: Can you clarify that in your answer so that I can retract my vote?

Comment: @Evk: I thought the definition of the event I am working with does not confirm to the EventPattern observable constructor. Is that incorrect? If yes, how would you use the EventPattern to create this observabler?

Comment: @LuisDelgado your event is (object sender, SomeEventArgs e) so it does conform to standard .NET pattern for events. You can use the code provided in this answer. Note that instead of pure SensorValueChangedEventArgs your observable will be of EventPattern<SensorValueChangedEventArgs> objects.